# Get the type of a class property's getter/setter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

As TypeScript class properties can have getters and setters of different types [since 4.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-3/#separate-write-types), I don't know who to get correctly a property's getter and setter's types.

===

As a class property is considered as a variable, I can't distinguish properly if the given property does have a getter nor/and setter and their type (as `Parameters<I>` and `ReturnType<I>` can only work on a function/method).

Some ideas of the expected result:

```
class Foo {
    get bar(): number { /** ... */ }
    set bar(baz: string) { /** ... */ }
}

type GetterOfFooBar = GetterOf<typeof Foo.prototype.bar>; // number
type SetterOfFooBar = SetterOf<typeof Foo.prototype.bar>; // string
```

```
class Foo {
    get bar(): number { /** ... */ }
}

type GetterOfFooBar = GetterOf<typeof Foo.prototype.bar>; // number
type SetterOfFooBar = SetterOf<typeof Foo.prototype.bar>; // never
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any use of the type system to observe the property type of a variant accessor will result in the type that you *read*, not the type that you *write*.  Which means `GetterOf<T>` is easy but `SetterOf<T>` is impossible.

This doesn't seem to be very well documented.  It is mentioned in the discussion of [microsoft/TypeScript#53417](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53417) at [microsoft/TypeScript#53594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53594):

> We always pick the read types.

as well as the implementation notes at [microsoft/TypeScript#42425](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42425):

> The type system remains entirely covariant in other operations! This has some effects that may not be immediately apparent: ... Types with variant getters/setters are effectively reduced to their `get` side when put through mapped types ... The type `T[K]` still means the *read* type of `K` on `T`

There is a request at [microsoft/TypeScript#43729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43729) to allow the setter type to be queried.  It's also possible that if the request at [microsoft/Typescript#43826](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43826) to support variant accessors in mapped types and index signatures is implemented, it will allow the setter type to be isolated and thus queried.  But for now this is not part of the language.

Comment: Tried on [TypeScript 5.2.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmAXR8BOB5AdiAntA3gFDTQDmS0AZgPbUAUAlAFzSYCuAtgEZoHQD0AKkHQAdOOiD+0AL6E5hUJBgBlJCgzY8REhAo16XMAC8WERKgCWmUgz5CR40ZOlyFSqNABC1RAAsCYjJ9WkYWdm5efAFhMQkpWSC9RCpQo1NocysbO2iHOOcEt0JCRBwAB3g4dTQsXAAxWmgAXmgyyupKauRarVFy1F9fCvhRAwBuAWkInlRSkeg1Hs0Gptb2+E7FmpWcfsHEYcqx2kn+aSzrUnnK718-OpxG6ha2ka2ff32hjZPqM+mnFmQA), I noticed that `typeof myProperty` can retrieve the setter's type instead of the getter's, if this one doesn't exist. So both the getter and the setter's types doesn't seem to be well isolatable.

Comment: TS has no concept of "getterless" or "writeonly" unfortunately, meaning your example is essentially where TS pretends there is also a getter of the same type as the setter.  That's an even worse problem (see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRPGLm)) and is probably off topic here